# What is causing this weird shading effect in rendered view?

Tags: 3d-view, shaders

[image: ?]

Whenever i look at some textures like the one in the pic i get a weird pixelated effect but looking through the camera it looks fine. Does anyone know what causes this

Comment: Do you have enough samples? What is the texture? (upload it if you can) What is your full node setup for this texture?

Comment: Are you using displacement? Are there enough subdivisions?

Comment: it seems to be a problem with everything in the viewport and not a particular texture. I have the samples set at 32 but tried higher and it didnt change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with backface culling. I turned that on and subdiv+ smooth shading and it seems to have solved the problem.